# Wordpress add class to specific menu item

Tags: wordpress, class, menu, addition

I have an onepage template. Menu has Home, Services, Blog, Contact etc and working with `<div id="blog">`. If someone clicks menu item "Blog" goes to `domain.com/#blog`. If click on blog title goes to `domain.com/blog/blog-title`. In this page i want an active class in menu item "Blog". This is my code

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'my_nav_special_class' , 10 , 2);
function my_nav_special_class($classes, $item){
    if(( is_page_template( 'page-blog.php' ) ) && ($item->title == 'BLOG')) {
        $classes[] = 'active';
    }   
    return $classes;
}
```

While loading page menu item "Blog" is active. When stops loading menu item "Home" is active.

How can i keep `class="active"` only in menu item "Blog" ?

Comment: It sounds like the class is being overridden by JavaScript. PHP is interpreted server side...so PHP won't be responsible for changing the classes after the page is done loading.

Comment: I renamed all javascripts and i found which is the problem. Now i'm going to edit it. Thank you.